# Boost auto link is trying to link with boost library that doesn't exist

Tags: c++, boost, linker, clang, autolink

When I tried to build my project with `Boost library iostreams` using `Clang on Windows` without using `CMake`, I get bunch of link errors. When I'm using `Boost auto link` I get error that the linker can't open file `boost_iostreams-clangw15-mt-x64-1_81.lib`, which doesn't exist. When I disable the Boost auto link using the `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` definition and try to link to the existing `boost_iostreams-clang15-mt-x64-1_81.lib` lib file manually, I get bunch of unresolved external symbol errors.

I tried to ask `ChatGPT` what does the `w` character before the compiler name in lib file name stands for. He doesn't seem to know either. First he suggested that the `w` character stand for `wide character support` and I need to build the `Boost libraries` with `ICU (International Components for Unicode)` library. Then he suggested that the `w` character stands for `Windows MSVC 2017`. Any ideas how could I fix this issue?

**This is the command I used for generating `Boost library iostreams`:**

`b2 --toolset=clang --with-iostreams`

Comment: Without using CMake, then use what VS?

Comment: I'm using VS code

Comment: `clangw` is clang for windows: https://github.com/boostorg/config/blob/develop/include/boost/config/auto_link.hpp#L223. Where did you get your boost build from?

Comment: From the official download page https://www.boost.org/users/download/.

Comment: but that only contains source releases and msvc builds?

Comment: From where should i download the Boost library for Clangw? With the Boost library distribution I downloaded I managed to build Boost lib files, but without the w character in front of the compiler name (in my case Clang). I just need to build the libraries with w character in front of the compiler name or tell the Boost auto link to stop using the lib files with the w character.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working.

**This is the updated command I used for generating `Boost library iostreams`:**

`b2 --layout=versioned --build-type=complete --with-iostreams -s ZLIB_SOURCE=%PATH_TO_ZLIB% --toolset=clang-win --variant=release`